# How to reuse <image> tags in SVG <defs>?

Tags: svg

I have a situation where to save on memory and loading, I am trying to reuse a single `<image>` tag in an SVG, instead of referencing the same xlink:href in several `<image>` tags.

My research has shown that `<use>` is the tag to reference a defined object.

However, when I try to reference an image, particularly inside a pattern (which is what I am trying to do), I get nothing, where using an image tag works fine.

What am I doing wrong? Is this even possible? I tried searching, but could not find any examples of the `<use>` tag with an image, just rects, paths, groups, etc.

```
<svg version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" 
       x="0px" y="0px" viewBox="0 0 1024 600"  >
<style type="text/css">
    .fillme{fill:url(#tsmall)}
</style>
<defs>
    <image id="texture" xlink:href="texture.tiny.png" />
    <pattern id="tsmall" patternUnits="userSpaceOnUse" width="486" height="402">
        <use xlink:href="#texture" x="0" y="0" width="486" height="402" />
    </pattern>
    <pattern id="tlarge" patternUnits="userSpaceOnUse" width="972" height="804">
        <use xlink:href="#texture" x="0" y="0" width="972" height="804" />
    </pattern>
</defs>
<rect x="0" y="0" width="1024" height="600" class="fillme"/>
</svg>
```

Comment: After a few minutes of googling, I don't see anything that says you can use  <use> with PNG. Perhaps try replacing your PNG with an SVG element? At least if that works you can eliminate other syntax errors as the cause of your problems.

Comment: @Taraz back to google school for you then. [Any ‘svg’, ‘symbol’, ‘g’, graphics element or other ‘use’ is potentially a template](https://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/struct.html#UseElement) and image is a [graphics element](https://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/intro.html#TermGraphicsElement)

Comment: @Taraz, I didn't see anything that said you couldn't either, which is why I asked :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

SVG image elements must have width and height attributes, yours doesn't.

An image is a graphics element and if you point a `<use>` at a graphics element the `<use>` width and height are ignored [per the SVG specification](https://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/struct.html#UseElement) (since it's not a symbol or an svg element it falls into the **Otherwise** case in the specification)

Comment: Could a similar effect be achieved with transforms? like `<use xlink:href="..." transform="scale(200%)"/>` ?